# Issue with opening pdf file with intent

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I am trying to open a PDF file using an `Intent`, but the PDF viewer closes as soon as it starts. It does show the filename, which is the same as what I tried to open.

Here is my code:

```
if (mimetype.equals("application/pdf") && file.isFile()) {
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, mimetype);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: What version of Android?  You aren't using Storage Access Framework, so the pdf app may not have access to your file.  If that isn't it, then your file has some error or feature the viewer doesn't support, there's nothing you can do about that.

Comment: `You aren't using Storage Access Framework, so the pdf app may not have access to your file. ` ??? FileProvider is used. No need for SAF.

Comment: Did you check file.canRead() before calling your code?

Comment: @blackapps I just checked it with file.canRead(), and it returns false. What can I do about it? I already have Storage permissions, and the file was downloaded in the Documents directory.

Comment: @GabeSechan I can open the same pdf from file explorer perfectly, so the file is perfectly fine.

Comment: Who downloaded that file? Not your app i suppose.

Comment: @blackapps my app downloaded it using DomnloadManager.

Comment: Then file.canRead() should return true. Otherwise use the uri the downloadmanager gives you for the file.

Answer (score 0):

check this is worked for me

```
if (checkPermission()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                intent.setType("application/pdf");
                startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_VIDEO_REQUEST);

            } else {
                requestPermission();

            }
```

check permission fun

```
private boolean checkPermission() {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(NewPaymentActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
```

request permission func

```
private void requestPermission() {

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(NewPaymentActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_VIDEO_REQUEST);
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(NewActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrong code. You do not need any permission to use ACTION_GET_CONTENT.

Comment: Not what I want.

Comment: use once check it. this worked for me